# Did the pre-cataclysmic landmass of Thuria end up being today's Americas?

Tags: robert-e-howard

All fans of Robert E. Howard's work are familiar with this map of the pre-Cataclysmic era of King Kull's time, some 6,000 years before Conan:

[image]

From reading [Howard's famous essay on the chronology of his fictitious world](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hyborian_Age) I have always understood that sunken Atlantis was in today's Atlantic Ocean and that the western part of the Thurian continent where Valusia was located would end up being the western part of the continent of the Hyborian kingdoms in the Conan era and, later, the western part of the Old World.

[image]

But I have just read that according to [**Official Handbook of the Marvel Universe Mystic Arcana: The Book of Marvel Magic #1**](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Thuria#cite_note-.0A.3B_.5B.5BZhered-Na_.28Earth-616.29.7CZhered-Na.5D.5D.27s_entry-5) the Thurian continent is not the ancestor of the Old World but of the Americas. Can anyone confirm or refute this statement?

Comment: Since Robert E Howards books was not published by the Marvel company, and Marvels version of Conan did things that Robert E Howard's original character didn't, like meeting some of the marvel heroes. Isn't it safe to assume they lived in different universes that had a different fate for the continent of Thuria?

Comment: Marvel Comics comic book stories of Kull and Conan are original stories and  adaptations of Robert E. Howard stories in a different medium than the original pulp fiction.  Thus they are in a different continuity.  It is possible that the Thurian Continent & Atlantis are in different locations in the two continuities.  if Marvel published a map showing Thuria EAST of Atlantis that would make it unlikely any part of the Thurian continent ever became part of the Americas in Marvel continuity.  But maybe the map and the Official Handbook are from two different Marvel continuities.